# Counting valleys traversed below sea level, given elevation changes

Tags: programming-challenge, functional-programming, scala, immutability

[Problem Statement](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/counting-valleys/problem?h_l=interview&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=interview-preparation-kit&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=warmup):

> Gary is an avid hiker. He tracks his hikes meticulously, paying close
>   attention to small details like topography. During his last hike he
>   took exactly steps. For every step he took, he noted if it was an
>   uphill, or a downhill,  step. Gary's hikes start and end at sea
>   level and each step up or down represents a  unit change in altitude.
>   We define the following terms:
>
> A mountain is a sequence of consecutive steps above sea level,
>   starting with a step up from sea level and ending with a step down to
>   sea level. A valley is a sequence of consecutive steps below sea
>   level, starting with a step down from sea level and ending with a step
>   up to sea level. Given Gary's sequence of up and down steps during his
>   last hike, find and print the number of valleys he walked through.
>
> For example, if Gary's path is, he first enters a valley units deep.
>   Then he climbs out an up onto a mountain units high. Finally, he
>   returns to sea level and ends his hike.
>
> #### Function Description
>
> Complete the `countingValleys` function in the editor below. It must
>   return an integer that denotes the number of valleys Gary traversed.
>
> `countingValleys` has the following parameter(s):
>
> - `n`: the number of steps Gary takes
> - `s`: a string describing his path
>
> #### Input Format
>
> The first line contains an integer, the number of steps in Gary's
>   hike.  The second line contains a single string, of characters that
>   describe his path.
>
> #### Output Format
>
> Print a single integer that denotes the number of
>   valleys Gary walked through during his hike.

My solution goes like this :

```
def countingValleys(n: Int, s: String): Int = {
  def rec(path: List[Char], counter: Int, valleys: Int): Int = {
    path match  {
      case Nil => valleys
      case x::xs if (x == 'U') && ((counter + 1) == 0) =>
        rec(xs, counter+1, valleys+1 )
      case x::xs if x == 'U' => rec(xs, counter +1, valleys)
      case x::xs if x == 'D' => rec(xs, counter -1, valleys)
    }
  }
  rec(s.toList, 0, 0)
}
```

Sample Input:

```
8
UDDDUDUU
```

Sample Output:

```
1
```

I wonder if there is a more idiomatic solution in functional programming style.

Comment: Side question about the problem - is the number of steps (`n`) redundant information? Won't that always be `s.length`?

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely correct. Function was provided this way. I will report the question on Hacker-Rank.

Comment: @Sandio adding `n` as an additional information is necessary for languages like C++ that don't perform the same level of behind-the-scenes memory management as other languages

Comment: Oh. That makes sense. @Vogel612 Thank you for the information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `counter` is a cumulative sum of elevation changes; `elevation` would be a more precise name for it.

Ultimately, the goal is to count the number of times the elevation changes from -1 to 0.  To do that:

1. Translate the `'U'` and `'D'` steps into `+1` and `-1`, respectively.
2. Obtain a sequence representing the elevation profile of the hike using [`Seq.scan`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Seq.html#scan[B>:A](z:B)(op:(B,B)=>B):CC[B]).
3. Count the number of times -1 is followed by 0 in the elevation profile, using [`Seq.sliding(2)`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Seq.html#sliding(size:Int):Iterator[C]) and [`Iterator.count`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Iterator.html#count(p:A=>Boolean):Int).

```
def countingValleys(n: Int, s: String): Int = s
  .map(_ match {case 'U' => +1; case 'D' => -1})
  .scan(0)(_+_)
  .sliding(2)
  .count(_ == Vector(-1, 0))
```

Comment: This is so out of the box. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with or "not functional" about your approach. This might be opinion territory, but personally I would consider using `foldLeft` as it might be more readable and you can potentially eliminate some of the complexity of your cases.

(also I got rid of `n` here as it is completely irrelevant, I know it's a problem from a website so you have to follow the format they gave you)

```scala
def countingValleys (steps: String): Int = steps
  .foldLeft((0, 0)) {
    case ((valleys, elevation), 'D') => (valleys, elevation - 1)
    case ((valleys, -1), 'U') => (valleys + 1, 0)
    case ((valleys, elevation), _) => (valleys, elevation + 1)
  }
  ._1
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. It is helpful.

Comment: Note that the original code's `counter` is what you call `depth`. That's a bit confusing, since positive `depth` represents higher elevation. Also, the original code's `valleys` is what you call `counter`. I think `valleys` was a clearer name.

Comment: @200_success good point on the naming, updated.